# Regular expression for RGBA value in php

Tags: javascript, php, regex, rgba

This is my regular expression for RGBA value in PHP.
It is supposed to accept both the percentage pattern and the non-percentage pattern.

```
function isValidColor_RGBA($color){


$pattern = "rgba\(
         ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}
         ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)
         (,\s*(0\.\d+|1))
         \)
        |rgba\(((\d|[1-9]\d|100)%\,\s?){3}(0|0?\.\d+|1|1\.0+)\)";



return (preg_match("<$pattern>", $color) == 1)? true : false;
}
```

This works in this JS tester:
https://regex101.com/r/A2IjNO/4
but didn't work in php.
What's wrong with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code where you use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try removing the new lines and unwanted spaces?

I tried with the below expression in [www.regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

> ^(#[\da-f]{3}|#[\da-f]{6}|rgba(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2} ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)(,\s*(0.\d+|1)))|hsla(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)(,\s*(0.\d+|1)))|rgb(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)|hsl(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)))$

It seems like the new lines and spaces making issues with PHP regex validation. The expression will work on both `js` and `PHP`

I tried the below code in [enter link description here](http://phpfiddle.org)

```
$pattern = '/^(\#[\da-f]{3}|\#[\da-f]{6}|rgba\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2} ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|hsla\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|rgb\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)|hsl\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\))$/';
$color = 'rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.5)';
var_dump(preg_match($pattern, $color));
```

**Keep in mind that you need to add white spaces. Because, you added `\s` before/after the comma symbols**